# Problems getting a LinearLayout to stay on the bottom - Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, gravity

I have an action bar fixed on top, a ScrollView which contains the main UI stuff, and a footer I want to keep on the bottom of the screen (but am unable to do). Note: I made a layout green and another red for debugging.

XML-wise, I have a base XML file, which I populate later:

base_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <include layout="@layout/actionbar" />

   <ScrollView
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:fillViewport="true"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/main_menu_layout"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:background="#00FF00"  <!-- Note: GREEN -->
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Some activitys will have the PrefsBar and some won't, which is why I don't have the "include layout="@layout/prefs_bar"" inside the base_layout.xml file (see below)... and why I didn't use a RelativeLayout.

Inside my activity I do the following:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);

      LinearLayout emptyMainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_menu_layout);
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View menuRowLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tools_kvar, null);
      emptyMainLayout.addView(menuRowLayout);
```

The tools_kvar.xml file contains:

```
 <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#FF0000" >   <!-- Note: RED -->

      <ScrollView
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:fillViewport="true"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

         <TableLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:stretchColumns="2">
             < .... ETC .... >
         </TableLayout>
      </ScrollView>

      <include layout="@layout/prefs_bar" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

First question: Why doesn't the main LinearLayout in tools_kvar.xml (RED) fill all the outer layout? The android:layout_height="fill_parent" is set!.

The prefs_bar.xml (seen included above) is what I need to be fixed on the bottom of the screen. It contains:

```
 <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/prefs_bar_layout"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/evengrayer"
      android:gravity="bottom"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom">

      <TextView  ... ETC ...
 </LinearLayout>
```

The current result is this:

[image: Current result]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not use `Relative layout` instead and apply `android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"` attribute?

Comment: Some activitys will have the PrefsBar and some won't, which is why I don't have the "include layout="@layout/prefs_bar"" inside the base_layout.xml file (see below)... and why I didn't use a RelativeLayout. A solution would be to create two "base_layout.xml" files, one with the prefs bar and another without, I guess.

Comment: Yeah. That seems to be a possible solution. I don't see a way around to keep your PrefsBar pinned down to the bottom using Linear Layout. But the UI you wish to achieve can be set with just Relative Layout. I think it'll be helpful if you can elaborate on why you'd want to stick to Linear Layout and Scroll View.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change tools_kvar.xml with given code block for scroll view

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="2" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test" />
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Just tried that, but no change. I think I'll just go for the RelativeLayout  =[